# Grid how to have multiple columns in one

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to append two columns bound into one kendo grid column.
Below doesn't seem to work.

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: { data: SomeData },
                columns: [{
                    field: "Column1" + "Column2"
                }]

            }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you do not need to edit the cell you can do what is known as *composed cells or composition* and it is implemented using KendoUI [`template`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnstemplate-string). (Try googling for "kendoui grid with composed cells").

Example

```
var leitmotifs = [
    { 
        company: "OnaBai", 
        leitmotif: "Working on a cloud of documents!" 
    },
    { 
        company: "Nike", 
        leitmotif: "Just do it!" 
    }
];

var grid = $("#table").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: leitmotifs
    },
    columns   : [
        { 
            title: "Company", 
            template: "#= company + ' : ' + leitmotif #"
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Did you have a look at the [schema.parse](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schemaparse-function) method on the DataSource?  You can add up columns there as new fields with no issues. Then the field would be available when you get to the grid.

```
dataSource: {
  transport: {
    read: "things"
  },
  schema: {
    parse: function (data) {
      // return a new collection which has a new field
      // that adds fields 2 and 3 together
      return $.map(data, function(item) {
       item.field4 = item.field2 + item.field3;
          return item;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example...

http://jsbin.com/azizaz/1/edit

Answer (score 5):

Here is a different solution that also provides the ability to sort independently on either field while still preserving a single column of data.

```
columns: [
   {  // cell data 
      headerAttributes: { style: "display:none;" },
      attributes: { colspan: 2 },
      template: "#= field1 # #= field2 #"
   },
   {  // field 1 data
      field: "field1",
      title: "Field 1",
      attributes: { style: "display: none;" },
      template: ""
   },
   {  // field 2 data
      field: "field2",
      title: "Field 2",
      attributes: { style: "display: none;" },
      template: ""
   }
]
```

Comment: this actually breaks the intended outcome @PatrickRoberts, setting hidden:true hides the whole column including the header cell, my approach preserves the header cell.

Comment: I don't claim to remember my reasoning from 3 years ago, but I was aware that it would affect the outcome, thus the comment instead of an edit. I now see the purpose of your usage, and perhaps I didn't notice 3 years ago.